# How to initialize a 2D array with same values in c++

Tags: c++, arrays, stl, initialization

WE can use fill_n function to initialize 1D array with value.

```
int table[20];
fill_n(table, 20, 100);
```

But how can we initialize 2D array with same values.

```
int table[20][20];
fill_n(table, sizeof(table), 100); //this gives error
```

Comment: use a loop to initialize

Comment: Yes i agree i can use loop. i was looking for any short and clean way.

Comment: Actually, your first will result in [*undefined behavior*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) as you write `20 * sizeof(int)` entries, which is well beyond the bounds of the array.

Comment: Ohh. so i think i should use 20, not sizeof(table).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [fill_n](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/fill_n) you can write:

```
std::fill_n(&table[0][0], sizeof(table) / sizeof(**table), 100);
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use a pointer to the first element and a pointer to one past the last one:

```
int table[20][20];
int* begin = &table[0][0];
size_t size = sizeof(table) / sizeof(table[0][0]);
fill(begin, begin + size, 100);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector):

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> table(20, std::vector<int>(20, 100));
```

All done and "filled" at the declaration. No more code needed.

Comment: Not the same data layout though. They might actually want contiguous data.

Comment: imho, suggesting a whole different alternative should be a comment... You're not answering the question.

Comment: @leemes It is a solution to the problem stated in the question, that's why I put it as an answer. If there was a way of doing this simple with `std::array` that would be even better.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg The question only mentions an array. Of course, you were thinking out of the box which is good, and your advice is really good, but still, you're not answering the question. (PS. I'm not the downvoter)